# No response from HttpServlet with AsyncContext

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, server-sent-events

I'm trying to implement async servlet on Tomcat, that will send update to client every time an `HttpSessionAttributeListener.attributeReplaced()` is triggered. Client side is configured to receive Server Sent Events.

Although the listener receives the updates, the browser does not receive any response. Browser's developer pane shows, that the request is `pending` and it ends with error `500` after the timeout set by the `AsyncContext.setTimeout()`. I run out of ideas, why this is happening.

**JS**

```
var source = new EventSource('/acount/sse');

source.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    document.querySelector('#messageArea p').innerHTML += event.data;
};
```

And this is my servlet code:

**Servlet**

```
public class SSE extends HttpServlet implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    public static final String ATTR_ENTRY_PROCESSOR_PROGRESS = "entryProcessorProgress";

    private AsyncContext aCtx;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);

        resp.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        resp.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        aCtx = req.startAsync(req, resp);
        aCtx.setTimeout(80000);

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
        write(httpSessionBindingEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
        write(httpSessionBindingEvent);
    }

    private void write(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
        if (httpSessionBindingEvent.getName().equals(ATTR_ENTRY_PROCESSOR_PROGRESS)) {
            try {
                String message = "data: " + httpSessionBindingEvent.getValue() + "\n\n";
                aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().write(message);
                aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

I tried your code and there was a java.lang.NullPointerException  in:

```
 aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().write(message);
```

Because the aCtx is null.

You have mixed the Servlet and Listener, but when the Listeners methods are called, the AsyncContext initialization is not. Therefore nothings go to the browser.

I splitted your code in Servlet an Listener and smuggled the AsychContext object through a session attribute. So it was accessible in the listener.

And it works.

**The Complete Code:**

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Server Event Listener</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="messageArea">
<p></p>
</div>
<script>
var source = new EventSource('/yourPath/ServerSentEvent');

source.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    document.querySelector('#messageArea p').innerHTML += event.data;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Servlet:**

```
package testingThings.ServerSentEvent;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, value = {"/ServerSentEvent"})
public class ServerSentEvent extends HttpServlet { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // add @WebServlet(asyncSupported = true) instead
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855712/how-to-avoid-request-set-async-supported-true-to-enable-async-servlet-3-0-proces
        // req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);

        resp.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        resp.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        AsyncContext aCtx = req.startAsync(req, resp);
        aCtx.setTimeout(80000);

        // add a asyncContext a session Attribute
        req.getSession().setAttribute("asyncContext", aCtx);

        //start logging in listener
        req.getSession().setAttribute("entryProcessorProgress", "trigger output");
    }
}
```

**The HttpSessionAttributeListener:**

```
package testingThings.ServerSentEvent;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent;

@WebListener
public class SessionAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    public static final String ATTR_ENTRY_PROCESSOR_PROGRESS = "entryProcessorProgress";

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
        write(httpSessionBindingEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
        write(httpSessionBindingEvent);
    }

    private void write(HttpSessionBindingEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) {
        if (httpSessionBindingEvent.getName().equals(ATTR_ENTRY_PROCESSOR_PROGRESS)) {
            try {
                // get the AsyncContext from the session
                AsyncContext aCtx = (AsyncContext) httpSessionBindingEvent.getSession().getAttribute("asyncContext");
                String message = "data: " + httpSessionBindingEvent.getValue() + "<br>\n\n";
                aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().write(message);
                aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```