# Dispatch request to an Async Servlet from managed bean generate exception

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, servlet-3.0, weblogic12c

when a button click, I need to have stuff running in my background, so I have a async Servlet. From my managed bean, if I do redirect, it works great (meaning that it execute my `run()` method inside my class that `extends Runnable` correctly). Like this

```
String url = externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/ReportExecutionServlet";
externalContext.redirect(url);
```

But if I switch to dispatch, like this

```
externalContext.redirect("/ReportExecutionServlet");
```

it fail when I try to obtain the `AsyncContext`

```
AsyncContext aCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);
```

**The error is below**

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The async-support is disabled on this request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl
```

Any idea how to fix this please?

NOTE: This is how to execute my async servlet, just in case:

```
    AsyncContext aCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);            
    //delegate long running process to an "async" thread
    aCtx.addListener(new AsyncListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "ReportExecutionServlet handle async request - onComplete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "ReportExecutionServlet handle async request - onTimeout");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "ReportExecutionServlet handle async request - onError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "ReportExecutionServlet handle async request - onStartAsync");
        }
    });
    // Start another service
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);            
    executor.execute(new AsyncRequestReportProcessor(aCtx));
```

Comment: SOLVED: I refer you to this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855712/how-to-avoid-request-set-async-supported-true-to-enable-async-servlet-3-0-proces?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF 2.x does not support async feature, so that why it is not working. More information can be found here [FacesServlet Servlet 3.0 Async Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679790/facesservlet-servlet-3-0-async-support)